# Ayuda java ejercicio día de mayor y menor ahorro

Tags: java

Hice un programa en java que lee una cantidad de dinero para cada día de la semana e imprime la mayor cantidad ahorrada, la menor cantidad ahorrada y el total ahorrado. Pero necesito imprimir también el día de la semana con mayor ahorro y el de menor ahorro. Cabe mencionar que no se puede utilizar arreglos, solo if, switch y ciclos.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int total = 0, menor = 0, mayor = 0, cahorradadiaria = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Escribe tu monto ahorrado cada día de la semana");
    for (int i = 1; i<=7; i++) {
        switch(i) {
        case '1':
            System.out.println("Lunes: "); break;
        case '2':
            System.out.println("Martes: "); break;
        case '3':
            System.out.println("Miercoles: "); break;
        case '4':
            System.out.println("Jueves: "); break;
        case '5':
            System.out.println("Viernes: "); break;
        case '6':
            System.out.println("Sabado: "); break;
        case '7':
            System.out.println("Domingo: "); break;
        }
        cahorradadiaria = sc.nextInt();
        total = total + cahorradadiaria;
        if(i==1) {
            menor = cahorradadiaria;
            mayor = cahorradadiaria;
        }
        if (menor > cahorradadiaria) {
            menor = cahorradadiaria;
        }
        if (mayor < cahorradadiaria) {
            mayor = cahorradadiaria;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El total de tu ahorro es: " + total);
    System.out.println("La mayor cantidad ahorrada es: " + mayor);
    System.out.println("La menor cantidad ahorrada es: " + menor);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente ya tienes el proceso para saber que día es en el que ahorras mas y en cual menos ya que la variable "i" representa el día.

Agrega las variables que almacenaran los días:

```
String diaMenor = "",diaMayor = "",dia = "";
```

Puedes agregar al switch lo siguiente:

```
switch(i) {
    case 1:
        System.out.println("Lunes: "); 
        dia = "Lunes";
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Martes: "); break;
        dia = "Martes";
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Miercoles: "); break;
        dia = "Miercoles";
        break;
    case 4:
        System.out.println("Jueves: "); break;
        dia = "Jueves";
        break;
    case 5:
        System.out.println("Viernes: "); break;
        dia = "Viernes";
        break;
    case 6:
        System.out.println("Sabado: "); break;
        dia = "Sabado";
        break;
    case 7:
        System.out.println("Domingo: "); break;
        dia = "Domingo";
        break;
    }
```

Modificas tus condicionales para asignar en las variables diaMenor y diaMayor sus respectivos valores:

```
if(i==1) {
    menor = cahorradadiaria;
    mayor = cahorradadiaria;
    diaMenor = "El dia con menor ahorro es: " + dia;
    diaMayor = "El dia con mayor ahorro es: " + dia;
}

if (menor > cahorradadiaria) {
    menor = cahorradadiaria;
    diaMenor = "El dia con menor ahorro es" + dia;
}
if (mayor < cahorradadiaria) {
    mayor = cahorradadiaria;
    diaMayor = "El dia con mayor ahorro es" + dia;
}
```

Por último imprimes los valores de diaMenor y diaMayor:

```
System.out.println(diaMenor);
System.out.println(diaMayor);
```

Modificado
Codigo Corregido:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    int total = 0, menor = 0, mayor = 0, cahorradadiaria = 0;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String diaMenor = "",diaMayor = "",dia = "";
    System.out.println("Escribe tu monto ahorrado cada día de la semana");
    for (int i = 1; i<=7; i++) {
        switch(i) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Lunes: "); 
            dia = "Lunes";
            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println("Martes: "); 
            dia = "Martes";
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Miercoles: "); 
            dia = "Miercoles";
            break;
        case 4:
            System.out.println("Jueves: "); 
            dia = "Jueves";
            break;
        case 5:
            System.out.println("Viernes: "); 
            dia = "Viernes";
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Sabado: "); 
            dia = "Sabado";
            break;
        case 7:
            System.out.println("Domingo: "); 
            dia = "Domingo";
            break;
        }
        cahorradadiaria = sc.nextInt();
        total = total + cahorradadiaria;
        if(i==1) {
            menor = cahorradadiaria;
            mayor = cahorradadiaria;
            diaMenor = "El dia con menor ahorro es: " + dia;
            diaMayor = "El dia con mayor ahorro es: " + dia;
        }
        if (menor > cahorradadiaria) {
            menor = cahorradadiaria;
            diaMenor = "El dia con menor ahorro es: " + dia;
        }
        else
        {
            mayor = cahorradadiaria;
            diaMayor = "El dia con mayor ahorro es: " + dia;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("El total de tu ahorro es: " + total);
    System.out.println("La mayor cantidad ahorrada es: " + mayor);
    System.out.println("La menor cantidad ahorrada es: " + menor);
    System.out.println(diaMenor);
    System.out.println(diaMayor);
}
```

Comment: Hola, primero que nada muchas gracias por tu ayuda, no quiero abusar de tu confianza pero al realizar los cambios correspondientes me aparece un error de inicialización en las variables dia, diaMenor y diaMayor sabes a que se deberá? pegaría el codigo pero no me darian los caracteres, si pudieras apoyarme te lo agradeceria bastante.

Comment: Hola, disculpa la tardanza, el error fue mio, el problema esta en el switch que coloque, puse la inicialización de la variable dia después del break de la condición, corrijo mi respuesta.

Comment: Ademas hago algunas modificaciones a tu código y dejo el código completo.

Comment: Sí eso era lo que me faltaba, gracias por el apoyo, sin duda por gente como tú es que esta comunidad sigue creciendo.